# Adjusting zindex with createjs

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, z-index, createjs

I would like to move the dragged item to the top layer when its moved.

How can I make sure it does not get dragged under another object.

Can I set what ever "sequenceNumbers" that is selected to move to the top of the sorting order?

```
 //++++++++          Terms to sort            ++++++++++++++++
        var xOffset = 100;
        for (var a = 0; a < gameData.Terms.length; a++) {
            rect = new createjs.Shape();
            rect.graphics.beginFill("blue").drawRoundRect(0, 0, 350, 30, 8);
            rect.name = a;

            var name = new createjs.Text(gameData.Terms[a].Definition, "14pt arial bold", "white");
            name.id = gameData.Terms[a].Name;
            name.textAlign = "left";
            name.y = rect.y + 2;
            name.x = rect.x + 4;

            var sequenceNumbers = new createjs.Container();

            sequenceNumbers.landingSpot = landingSpots[a];
            landingSpots[a].sequenceNumber = sequenceNumbers;

            sequenceNumbers.addChild(rect, name);
            stage.addChild(sequenceNumbers);
            sequenceNumbers.x = 300;
            sequenceNumbers.y = xOffset;
            xOffset += 40;

            var startPositionX;
            var startPostitionY;

 sequenceNumbers.on('mousedown', function (e) {
                var posX = e.stageX;
                var posY = e.stageY;
                startPositionX = e.stageX;
                startPositionY = e.stageY;
                this.offset = { x: this.x - posX, y: this.y - posY };

            });

 sequenceNumbers.on("pressmove", function (evt) {
                evt.currentTarget.x = evt.stageX;
                evt.currentTarget.y = evt.stageY;
                var posX = evt.stageX;
                var posY = evt.stageY;
                this.x = posX + this.offset.x;
                this.y = posY + this.offset.y;

            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `this.css('z-index','500')`  to your `('mousedown')` call.

Comment: `sequenceNumbers.on('mousedown', function (e) { var posX = e.stageX; var posY = e.stageY; startPositionX = e.stageX; startPositionY = e.stageY; this.offset = { x: this.x - posX, y: this.y - posY }; this.css('z-index', '500') });` that didnt work hmmmm

Comment: Hmm.  I see now sequenceNumbers is a JS object.  You'd need to apply that z-index to the html object being moved.  I don't know createJS or I'd try to suggest more.  Apologies.

Comment: z-index doesn't exist in the EaselJS DisplayList. If you want it on top, just addChild() again, which will put it at the top of the container/stage's child list.

Comment: I tried to stage.adchild(sequenceNumbers); in my pressmove and mousedown and had no success. How would i properly apply that code?

Comment: It looks like sequenceNumbers is a container, so if you are trying to sort one of its children to the top, use `sequenceNumbers.addChild(evt.currentTarget);`